# Make a vte terminal communicate with running python script

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, vte

I am trying to achieve the following. I built some gtk application which will have some data, let's say a,b and c.

**What I want now is some sort of terminal window in which I can query and change the data as I would in e.g. iPython**:

```
$ a
[1 2 3]
$ a= a+1
$ a

[2 3 4]
```

And let this take effect in the gtk application. Is this doable?

Comment: do you have build your vte ?

Comment: Hi. I don't quite understand the question. How should I build it? But in general I have very little experience with these topics, so probably the answer to your question is "No".

Answer (score 0):

You can try to launch xterm by subprocess, and to communicate between file.py and term, copy the vars in environment variable, and get it by:

```
os.environ[your_var]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this. Once you are in type "python". About communicating with the script, the only way that I've found is with an external file. What you want it is possible but complicated. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235092/best-way-of-redirecting-output-to-a-vte-terminal) you have an example that i made where i return the variable "tty" from the VTE terminal to the python script.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, Vte
#GObject is not required. I just import it everywhere just in case.
#Gtk, Vte, and GLib are required.
from gi.repository import GLib
import os
#os.environ['HOME'] helps to keep from hard coding the home string.
#os is not required unless you want that functionality.

class TheWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="inherited cell renderer")
        self.set_default_size(600, 300)
        self.terminal     = Vte.Terminal()
        self.terminal.fork_command_full(
                Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, #default is fine
                os.environ['HOME'], #where to start the command?
                ["/bin/sh"], #where is the emulator?
                [], #it's ok to leave this list empty
                GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD,
                None, #at least None is required
                None,
                )
        #Set up a button to click and run a demo command
        self.button = Gtk.Button("Do The Command")
        #To get the command to automatically run
        #a newline(\n) character is used at the end of the
        #command string.
        self.command = "echo \"Sending this command to a virtual terminal.\"\n"
        command = Gtk.Label("The command: "+self.command)
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.InputToTerm)
        #end demo command code

        #set up the interface
        box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        box.pack_start(self.button, False, True, 0)
        box.pack_start(command, False, True, 1)
        #a scroll window is required for the terminal
        scroller = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scroller.set_hexpand(True)
        scroller.set_vexpand(True)
        scroller.add(self.terminal)
        box.pack_start(scroller, False, True, 2)
        self.add(box)

    def InputToTerm(self, clicker):
        #get the command when the button is clicked
        length = len(self.command)
        #A length is not required but is the easiest mechanism.
        #Otherwise the command must be null terminated.
        #Feed the command to the terminal.
        self.terminal.feed_child(self.command, length)


win = TheWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```